# Should a button consume mouse events?

Tags: c++, user-interface

Right now, my scrollbar is made up of 3 buttons (its children). The buttons currently consume mouse down, up, click, and drag. The scrollbar then hooks into these 3 buttons and does what it wants them to do. Therefore, I do not use the new bubble-up-the-stack feature of my GUI in this scenario.

I'm still not quite clear on when I should use this and when I should listen to child events.

Is my current technique a good way to do it, or should my button instead not consume these events and receive events intended for the buttons and do stuff based on that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the 3 buttons (I presume up, down, and slider) don't have enough information to do anything on their own; the best they can do is interact with the main scrollbar control and tell it what modifications it should make. In that case it might just be cleaner to have the scrollbar do all the message processing itself. It already needs to deal with things like arrow keys, correct?

Comment: Yes, it does. But I was having other problems with this bubbling system. For example, the scroll bar was not consuming the mouse move event and when the scrollbar was placed in a listbox, it caused the listbox to mousemove when it shouldn't have (the mouse was on the scrollbar) .. is event bubbling really needed for a gui, or is a system where for example a scrollpane hooks into all its children to get mouse wheel notifications acceptable?